# How to get the IdentityReference for "Everyone" to create MutexAccessRule on localized systems?

Tags: c#, localization, mutex, concurrency

I'd like to use the code as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223061/how-to-implement-single-instance-per-machine-application) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c) to create a system wide Mutex.
This works fine on most systems, but on a German XP installation I get the error that "Some or all identity references could not be translated". The problem is that the group "Everyone" is called "Alle" on this system.

So how do I get the correct IdentityReference to create a MutexAccessRule for "Everone" or "Users" on all systems independent of the OS language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Localized group name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663332/localized-group-name)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just found the solution by continuing searching. See the answer to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663332/localized-group-name):

```
new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null)
```

This can be used rather than "Everyone".

Can someone mark this question here as duplicate if found correct?

Comment: Namespace is System.Security.Principal