# Set default permissions when creating a new Message Queue (MSMQ) in C#

Tags: c#, permissions, msmq

I am trying to programmatically create several `Message Queues` on a Windows 2003x64/2008R2 Server.
When a Queue is created, Windows automatically applies default permissions to the Queue.

For MSMQ 4, the following users are added by default

- Everyone
- Creator of the queue
- ANONYMOUS LOGIN

When I set the permissions for a queue using `MessageQueue.SetPermissions()`, the specified `AccessControlList` is only appended to the default security permissions.

Is there any way the default permissions can be removed or overwritten?
In  [this MSDN Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/08/03/default-msmq-queue-permissions-have-changed-in-msmq-4-0.aspx) at the bottom, it states that

> You can't, though, customise the defaults as they are hard-coded.

I know that the settings of a queue are persisted in a file, located in `C:\Windows\System32\msmq\storage\lqs`. In this file there's a Security property that represents the permissions for the queue. Might editing this key be an option? Doing this, however, seems kind of odd to me.

I'm looking for a proper way to specify my own `AccessControlList` that overwrites the default security permissions of a queue. Either when it's being created, or afterwards.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can't remove or revoke permissions to those default groups you can always try to deny rights to them. Deny takes precedence over allow. This code works:

```
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(".\\Private$\\QueueName");
queue.SetPermissions("Everyone", MessageQueueAccessRights.ReceiveMessage,
        AccessControlEntryType.Deny);
```

Revoking permissions (`AccessControlEntryType.Revoke`) should also work though. Maybe there is an error in your code. Works on my machine.

The article says:

> You can't, though, customise the defaults as they are hard-coded.

and it means that you can't change what rights are given during queue creation but you can change them afterwards.

Edit: To get "Everyone" independent of OS-language: [How to get the IdentityReference for "Everyone" to create MutexAccessRule on localized systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614697/how-to-get-the-identityreference-for-everyone-to-create-mutexaccessrule-on-loc)

Comment: But since `Deny`s take precedence, and you're `Deny`ing Everyone this right, doesn't that mean that no-one can use the queue? Would `Revoke` be a better option?

Comment: Revoke is better if it works but you wrote you can't do it. It works when I try it. Try again with this code.

Comment: Yes `Revoke` works. However, how can I revoke the permissions for the Owner/Creator? This username is not always the same.

Comment: Just revoke for "Creator Owner".

Answer (score 6):

I had the same exact issue with the ACL.  When I switched to the SetPermissions() method things ran much better.

The code below works for me:

```
                queue.SetPermissions(
                    "Everyone",
                    MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl,
                    AccessControlEntryType.Allow);
                queue.SetPermissions(
                    "ANONYMOUS LOGON",
                    MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl,
                    AccessControlEntryType.Allow);
```

Answer (score 3):

Although Mike's answer is correct, it assumes the server has English as the language. If you use this code on a server which uses a different language (in this case Dutch) ...

```
 queue.SetPermissions( 
                     "Everyone",
                     MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl,
                      AccessControlEntryType.Allow);
```

... you get the following exception:

> Kan de naam Everyone niet omzetten (fout = 1332 ).
>   System.Messaging.AccessControlList.MakeAcl(IntPtr oldAcl)
>   bij System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SetPermissions(AccessControlList dacl)
>   bij System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SetPermissions(String user, MessageQueueAccessRights rights, AccessControlEntryType entryType)

which roughly translates to 'Cannot convert name 'Everyone'. Instead if you use this code you will get a localized version of 'Everyone':

```
using System.Security.Principal;

** code ommitted**

string everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
queue.SetPermissions( 
                   everyone,
                   MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl,
                    AccessControlEntryType.Allow);
```